# Find the segment ordinal number and the inner index for a given search index on a splitted array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe having 1 column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value": [10,9,5,11,2,8,6,7,4,2,1,9]})
```

If I take a subset of this, the starting index value changes from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 to 3,4,5,6,7:

```
df = df[3:8]
```

When I try to convert this into a numpy array using .to_numpy() as follows, then its indices get reset to 0,1,2,3,4. But I need to have them as 3,4,5,6,7 itself.

```
df_mod = df.to_numpy()
```

Can anyone please help to create this numpy array with the same indices as the pandas dataframe from which it was converted?

***EDIT {further context}:***

- I've a numpy array having 2880 index points. There's a particular index point in it - 1440 at which I need a marker.
- Now I need to split this main array into multiple segments - say 100 of them. And I need to identify in which out of these 100 segments is the marker present and at what index point of this particular segment is the marker present - say it's at index point 60.
- I would be splitting the main array into multiple segments other than 100 as well as needed. Hence, I need a modular code which would be able to implement this for any no. of segments. I need the segment no. and the index of the identified segment in which the marker is present.
- I thought that retaining the indices of the pandas df from which I obtained my numpy array would've helped in achieving this, but looks like the numpy array cannot have any other starting index value apart from 0, unlike pandas dataframes.

This is what I'm currently doing to create the segments:

```
# Convert pandas df to numpy array
signal = df['value'].values
# Split the signal into n no. of parts
num_parts = 100
segment_length = len(signal) // num_parts
segments = [signal[i:i + segment_length] for i in range(0, len(signal), segment_length)]
```

Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Numpy arrays don't have an "explicit" index, so I'm unsure what your expected output would be like. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I've added further context to my question. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

`NumPy` array, unlike `pandas`, does not provide labels for row indices.
To keep indices of the initial df slice you could do either:

`arr = df[3:8].reset_index().values`

---

```
array([[ 3, 11],
       [ 4,  2],
       [ 5,  8],
       [ 6,  6],
       [ 7,  7]])
```

so that the 1st and 2nd columns will represent the initial *index/value* respectively,

Or convert the slice to a numpy record array (with the DataFrame labels as fields) via [`DataFrame.to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html):

```
arr = np.array(df[3:8].to_records().data)
```

---

```
array([(3, 11), (4,  2), (5,  8), (6,  6), (7,  7)],
      dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('Value', '<i8')])
```

where you can access by field name like:

```
arr['index']
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

---

**Update:**

Mathematically, we can find the segment ordinal number and the inner index for a given search index, even without actually splitting the input array. 
I'll provide separate definitions for splitting an array on `N` segments and for finding *the segment ordinal number and the inner index for a given search index*:

```
# input array of 12 values
arr = pd.DataFrame({"value": [10, 9, 5, 11, 2, 8, 6, 7, 4, 2, 1, 9]}).values

def split_array(arr, seg_N):
    seg_size = arr.size // seg_N
    return np.split(arr, np.arange(1, seg_N) * seg_size)

def find_seg_by_idx(arr_size, seg_N, search_idx):
    """Find segment ordinal number and the inner position
       for a given search index
    """
    if search_idx >= arr_size:
        raise IndexError(f'{search_idx} is out of bounds')

    seg_size = arr_size // seg_N
    # segment ordinal number
    seg_num = min(search_idx // seg_size + 1, seg_N)
    # shift to the start of the segment to find the inner index
    inner_idx = search_idx - (seg_num * seg_size - seg_size)
    return seg_num, inner_idx
```

---

Usage:

```
print(split_array(arr, 5))  # split 12-values arr on 5 segments/parts

[array([[10],
       [ 9]]), array([[ 5],
       [11]]), array([[2],
       [8]]), array([[6],
       [7]]), array([[4],
       [2],
       [1],
       [9]])]
```

---

```
print(find_seg_by_idx(10, seg_N=3, search_idx=7))

(3, 1)
```

---

```
print(find_seg_by_idx(12, seg_N=5, search_idx=11))

(5, 3)
```

Comment: I've added further context to my question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @EnigmAI, Say we have a dataframe of `10` values, divided on `3` segments. What do you exactly expect as a result for a search index `7` ?

Comment: Say we've a df of 10 values, with the marker at index point 7. Now if I divide it into 3 parts - 
Part 1: index values 0,1,2;
Part 2: index values 3,4,5;
Part 3: index values 6,7,8,9.
I need the output to tell me that it's Part 3 that contains the marker 7 and that it lies at its index point 1.

Comment: @EnigmAI, see my update

Answer (score 0):

Providing a bit more of information such as why do you want to do that would be helpful

FPandas automatically add index, however when you use `to_numpy()` it becomes to an array which does not have any index cause the array itself if kind of index

```
[[Array1],
[Array2] 
..
[ArrayN]]
Etc
```

If you want to have an index linked to the datapoint you could use `.to_dict` (check the documentation)

```
orient(str) {‘dict’, ‘list’, ‘series’, ‘split’, ‘tight’, ‘records’, ‘index’}
```

and this would keep the index and data as

```
{'3': ABC , '4': CDE,...,}
```

Cheers

Comment: I've added further context to my question. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

A numpy array is positionally-indexed: a 1-dimensional numpy array like the one you have will always be indexed from `0` to `len(arr)-1`. So there is no way to have it exactly as you want.

However, if you just need to be able to use those indices to access the appropriate values, you could hack it by using a function or dictionary to translate the pandas indices into numpy indices:

```py
>>> def idx_translate(df_idx):
...     return list(df[3:8].index).index(df_idx)
>>> idx_translate(3)
0
>>> df_mod[idx_translate(3)]
11
```

```py
>>> idx_dict = {df_idx: idx for idx, df_idx in enumerate(df[3:8].index)}
>>> idx_dict[3]
... 0
>>> df_mod[idx_dict[3]]
... 11
```

Note that any slice would need its own function/dictionary. If you need more versatility you could write a class:

```py
class IndexTranslator():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.idx_dict = {df_idx: idx
                         for idx, df_idx
                         in enumerate(df.index)}
    def idx(self, df_idx):
        return self.idx_dict[df_idx]
```

This way you can just instantiate a new object of the class any time you make a new slice of a dataframe.

Comment: I've added further context to my question. Can you please take a look?